# Get VALUE from tkinter combo-box dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

I have a tkinter combobox populated by a dictionary with two fields: name, id. Using a callback function I can get the name field, but I need the ID field.

```
    var_person = tk.StringVar()
    cb = ttk.Combobox(root, values=list(my_dict.keys()),  
    textvariable=var_person)
    cb.grid(row=0, column=1)
    
        def callback(event):
            a = var_person.get()
            print (a)
    cb.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', callback)
```

Results: Prints the selected name, but I really need the id.

Thanks for any assistance.

John

Forgot to show the bind method

Comment: what do you mean by id?

Comment: Here is a sample of the dictionary that I am using to populate the cb.
{'Allen, Jamie': 2, 'Anderson, Abbie': 1391, 'Anderson, Marcie': 1380,
the first column (name) is in the drop down list. what I need is the 2nd field.
ie: Select Allen, Jamie and get the int 2

Comment: I also know that the following will print the id on the label_selected. I really just need the id number to run some other functions.
cb.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', lambda event: label_selected.config(text=my_dict[var_person.get()]))

Comment: I've added an answer, does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this example give you an idea? Nothing much is done, the combobox data is taken and the corresponding value from the dictionary is returned.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

def callback():
    key = var_person.get()
    try: #To bypass the error when user chooses nothing
        value = my_dict[key] #get the corresponding value from the given key
        print(value) #print it 
    except KeyError: 
        print('Please choose an option') #error message


my_dict = {'Allen, Jamie': 2,
           'Anderson, Abbie': 1391, 'Anderson, Marcie': 1380}

var_person = StringVar()
cb = ttk.Combobox(root, values=list(my_dict.keys()),  textvariable=var_person)
cb.current(1) #setting the current value to index position 1 of the list(optional)
cb.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

b = Button(root,text='Click me',command=callback).pack(pady=10,padx=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Let me know if any doubts :D

Cheers

Comment: Thank you very much!  That is exactly what I needed. Plus you added the error checking.